# Thesis style page numbering

Tags: page-numbering

I am writing a thesis report. In the report I want to start counting the page number from a specific chapter. Those would be in arabic. But before that chapter I want to number pages in roman. How would I do it?

To be specific assume following chapters are present in the thesis - `Certificate`, `List of Contents`, `Acknowledgement`, `Abstract`, `Chap 1: Introduction`, `Chap 2: ...`, `Chap 3: ...`, `Reference`, `Index`. I want to start counting the page from 1 from `Chap 1: Introduction`. But before that page numbers would be counted as roman. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at the beginning of your file, issue the command

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

when you want the page numbers to restart and change to arabic, issue the commands

```
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

`\pagenumbering` automatically resets the counter to "1".

some document classes have shortcuts for this, but you didn't say what class you're using.